# Populating a select list of connected nodes in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Still a noob at this wonderful d3 and having difficulties on using it. Please understand that I am not a programmer and I'm taking this up on self initiated interest. So I will be grateful for a layman explanation to be given.

I have created a d3 force layout. I am looking for a solution to dynamically populate a 'select' drop-down list of connected nodes. I.e if a user clicks on a node or select from the first drop-down list, another 'select' drop-down list appears with the list of connected nodes.

This was my unsuccessful approach.

```
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                  .data(graph.nodes);

    node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.size; })
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "node _" + d.size; })
        .attr("id", function (d) { return "n" + d.code ; })
        .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.group); })
        .on("mouseover", function(d) { highlight(d); })
        .on("mouseout", mouseout)
        .on('click', populate)
        .call(force.drag)
        ;

  var linkedByIndex = {};
    graph.links.forEach(function (d, i) {
        graph.links[i].source = graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].source);
        graph.links[i].target = graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].target);
        linkedByIndex[graph.links[i].source + "," + graph.links[i].target] = 1 ;
        });

    function isConnected(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index] || a.index == b.index;
    }

var select = d3.select("#search1") //first 'select' drop-down list//
    .append("select")
    .on('change.pcp', populate);

  select.selectAll("option")
    .data(graph.nodes.filter(function(d){return d.sel == "1";}))
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", function(d) {return d.code ;})
    .text(function(d) {return d.name ;});

   var select7 = d3.select("#viewList") //second 'select' drop-down list//
    .append("select")
    .on('change.sn', searchNode)
    ;

  select7.selectAll("option")
    .data(graph.nodes.filter(function (d){populate (d) ;}))
    .enter()
    .append("option")
    .attr("value", function(d) {return d.code ;})
    .text(function(d) {return d.name ;});
```

Then my function is as follows

```
function populate() { 
    name=[];
    var selectedVal = d3.event.target.value;
    //iterate through all the nodes
    graph.nodes.every(function(n){
      if (n.code == selectedVal){
        var d = n;
        d3.selectAll(".node")
            .data(nodeArray, filter(function (o) { 
                thisList = isConnected(d,o) ? 1: name;
                return thisList;
            }));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Please point out my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't change the structure of the links and nodes, this solution should work.

You need a something like that in your node composition :

```
// On click on the node
node.on('click',function(d) {
  // Iterate throw the links
  graph.links.forEach(function (l, i) {
       if (d === l.source )
       {
          console.log(l.target);
          d3.select("#list").append("p").text(l.target.name);
       }
       if (d === l.target )
       {
          console.log(l.source);
          d3.select("#list").append("p").text(l.source.name);
       }
   });

 });
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and let you know the outcome!

Comment: at the moment it is not working. The solution you provide only returns a list of currently clicked nodes and not the connected ones.

Comment: I have followed your example and did some alteration,           

.on('click',function(d) {
      // Iterate throw the links
      graph.nodes.forEach(function (l) {
        if (isConnected (d, l) == 1)
        {
        // Append your nodes to a list
         d3.select("#viewList").append("p").text(l.name);
        }
       });

     })

The thing now is that, it returns the connected nodes including the clicked node. How do I exclude the clicked node?

Comment: I have updated my post @R.Iskandar. This example should work.

Comment: Thanks! It is workable. However, can you please explain why you included the "i" in this line -"graph.links.forEach(function (l, i) {". Because if I remove the "i", it is still workable. The other thing is that I changed "forEach" to "filter" and it also works. Just thought of sharing with you. Anyway, I also have found an alternative solution by using the similar existing "isConnected" function.

Comment: I might have incorrectly used the term "select" list. I am actually looking for a "select" drop-down list. Your solution provides select list well. I attempted to put the list into a drop-down list and somehow it doesn't put it all in one list. (i.e if there are 4 connected nodes, there will be 4 drop-down list instead of 1) I am sorry for using the wrong term. I hope you can give a solution to that.

Comment: It depends the way you are working. 
Fisrt,**forEach() is equivalent to filter()**, if you had no conditions in your filter(). 
ForEach create a new array depending on a condition.
Secondly, i just iterate throw all of your data, it might be helpful if you want to know the index of the element you are working on. In your example, the node you search the link is **graph.nodes[i]**.
Thirdly, I understand what you want. Why you don't create an empty dropdown list, and you add links using D3 : 
**d3.select(this).append("text").html('First Line <br> Second Line')**

Comment: I'll give it a go and see how it works out. Thanks for the explanation! Makes it crystal clear. It is good that I now understand rather than blindly doing things based on trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Praise to God. I have found an answer following HugoLasticot's help. I had to modify a few things which were my "isConnected" function. I knew I had to utilise this function but just didn't know how. After a few trials and errors, I managed to find a solution. I used HugoLasticot way to "append the connected to a list". Thank you very much. Anyway, I created another "isConnected" function which is called "isConnected1" specifically for this purpose. It looks something like this.

```
    function isConnected1(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index];
    }
```

This defers from the isConnected function because it will not return the current clicked node.

```
        .on('click',function(d) {
              // Iterate throw the links
              graph.nodes.forEach(function (l) {
                   if (isConnected1 (d, l) == 1)
                   {
                      // Append your nodes to a list
                       d3.select("#viewList").append("option").text(l.name);
                   }
               });

             })
```

The downside of HugoLasticot's code was that it return the clicked node's name instead of the connected ones. Notice in the ".text(d.name)" is specific towards the node clicked. Even if we did this in the forEach function, it will only return that particular node. So I have instead wrote ".text(l.name)" so that it will narrow down other than "d.name".

I am still a novice in d3, hence having difficulties with my explanation and english is not my primary language. I hope this solution is beneficial to others who have similar difficulties. I also have to give credits towards HugoLasticot for showing how to append it in the list. Thank you.